# Simple scheme for backup virtual machine, which drawback of simple DD?

Tags: backup, dd, proxmox, ceph

We've been struggling to create the consistent scheme for backup of KVM virtual machines under [Proxmox](https://www.proxmox.com/) control and [Ceph](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Storage:_Ceph) as storage, but still quite often during the [vzdump](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Vzdump_manual) with a snapshot the virtual machine is going down

```
120: dic 05 04:51:47 INFO: status: 17% (21731147776/127775277056), sparse 0% (1095598080), duration 1225, 17/16 MB/s
120: dic 05 04:52:47 ERROR: VM 120 not running
120: dic 05 04:52:47 INFO: aborting backup job
120: dic 05 04:52:47 ERROR: VM 120 not running
120: dic 05 04:52:48 ERROR: Backup of VM 120 failed - VM 120 not running
```

Vzdump config

```
vzdump 120 --quiet 1 --mode snapshot --mailto <email> --node node1 --compress lzo --maxfiles 2 --storage backup01
```

Some of our customer proposed us the following strategy of the backup from the **inside** of the virtual machine, saying "it is that simple!"

```
   mount /nfs/backup
   dd if=/dev/sda of=/​nfs/backup/$datetime-$virtualmachine
```

​
What would be your opinion on this proposal? How to explain in a simple and profound terms that this is a really bad idea? And how to remain calm and polite in this situation:?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not going to work because the disk `/dev/sda` will be changing during the `dd` run and you end up with an inconsistent image.

Simpler explanation: Tell him that if you create a file towards the end of the backup, it will not be be backed up as the information where a file is located is at the beginning of the image and will not include the new file.

Better yet: Just demonstrate it. It's easy to do and the result is usually spectacular...

Comment: Thank you Sven, I plan to make an experiment with the MySQL database and show that after this procedure the database remain inconsistent and server does not start.